# Postgres - Change Role inside Do Block (anonymous code block)

Tags: postgresql

I would like to change the role inside a Do block (anonymous code block), but want to make sure the role will return to the original role once the Do block is exited.  I know I can add another set role command at the very end of the Do block, but I would like to know if it is possible to avoid it somehow.  If it is impossible to avoid adding the set role at the end of the Do block, how do I make sure that I do not exit the Do block without setting the original role back.

```
show role; -- it is postgres 
do $$ 
begin
  set role user1;
  -- do some action
end $$;
show role -- it is user1
```

Comment: [reset role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-role.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SET LOCAL` to change the role only for the current transaction.